# Make a new column without duplicates, count the frequency of a number, and sort the columns

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I would like to create an Excel macro that will do the following:
Take an arbitrary length list of numbers in column A
Copy the unique values to column D
Fill column E with a COUNTIF formula that will display how many times each unique number occurred (so it will have the unique number in D, and the number of times it occurred in E)
Sort the values of column D and E from highest to lowest, based on column E'
s values

I know how to do each of these steps with the Excel GUI, but I want to write a VBA macro to complete these steps. The hardest part for me so far is making the COUNTIF formula address an arbitrary length range. Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

EDIT:
Here's my latest recorded Code:

```
 Range("A1:A1000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range( _
        "D1:D2000"), Unique:=True
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R2C1:R1000C1,RC[-1])"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E1000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Columns("D:E").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E2:E1000") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("D1:E1000")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

I manually set the range to be a maximum of 1000, but I actually want to make it whatever the last cell is with data. I think I could do something like Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)) for the copy and paste parts, but COUNTIF won't accept that notation right?

Comment: First step: if you know how to do it with the GUI, but don't know how to do it in code, Record a Macro! (http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html) That will give you a starting point in code. From there, you can edit the code to act exactly the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COUNTIF might not allow that VBA Expression, but we can evaluate the expression first and then use that in place of "1000" anywhere it occurs! So:

```
Dim maxRow As Long
maxRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Range("A1:A" & maxRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range( _
    "D1:D" & maxRow), Unique:=True
Range("E2:E" & maxRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R2C1:R" & maxRow & "C1,RC[-1])"

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E2:E" & maxRow) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("D1:E" & maxRow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Basically just replacing 1000 with maxRow everywhere it occurs. Plus I cleaned up the uses of `Select` (because it's slow and prone to runtime errors).

Not sure why you used D2000 instead of D1000 back in the original code, so I changed it. If that was intentional and you wanted to actually copy into a range double the size of your input (why?) you can use `"D1:D" & (2 * maxRow)` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was using a variable to store the last cell with data at one point, but then I couldn't figure out the syntax for using it in the range. Also, the D2000 was a typo, it was supposed to be 1000 like the others.